# Dim part of autocomplete text that is extracted from json

Tags: jquery, json, autocomplete

I was wandering if there is any way to dim part of jQuery autocomplete in a text field. Let's say I search for a city and autocomplete returns json data. I want to output "Austin" in bold black letters and "TX" in light gray letters in the autocomplete text field.  Not sure if there is a way to do it. I can add in json `<span>` or whatever, it returns `<span>` value anyway in a text field, not listening to html tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the response before it is displayed using the `response` method.

```
$('#element').autocomplete({
    source: // source,
    response: function( event, ui ) {
        /* Here you can edit the values of the respose */
        alert('Item: ' + ui);
    }
});
```